# Check if files exists in 3 different directories and move them one to another

Tags: shell

I'm quite new in creating shell scripts.

I'm developing a shell script that will backup my files once a day only.
I need to check which *.war files are in three different folders (input folder, production folder, backup folder)

If the same files exists in the three directories, don't perform backup.
If it doesn't, it must move the files in folder 2 to folder 3.

This is what I've done so far.

===============================

```
TODAY=$(date +%d-%m-%Y)
INPUT=/home/bruno.ogasawara/entrada/
BACKUP=/home/bruno.ogasawara/backup/
PROD=/home/bruno.ogasawara/producao/
DIR1=$(ls $INPUT)
DIR2=$(ls $PROD)
DIR3=$(ls $BACKUP$TODAY)

for i in $DIR1; do
    for j in $DIR2; do
        for k in $DIR3; do
                if [ $i == $j ] && [ $j == $k ]; then
                          exit 1; else
                          mv -f $PROD$j $BACKUP$TODAY
                fi
        done
    done
done

mv -f $INPUT*.war $PROD
```

===============================

The verification is not working. Only thing working is the `mv -f $INPUT*.war $PROD` in the end.
Where am I missing something or doing something wrong?

Thanks in advance people.

Answer (score 0):

What I understand is you want to sync those three folders.

In that case you should not modify the file names as we are using file names to compare them.Otherwise you should use md5 or sha checksums.But linux filesystem already has timestamps feature you don't have to attach date to filename.

*In your code you used ls to list files ...but actually ls command lists files in column mode which is not comaptible with for loop in bash.

correct command is*

> find $DIR -maxdepth 1 -type f -exec basename {} \;

**you want to sync the *.war files to all folders...then simply you can use this:**

```
#!/bin/bash
DIR1=/home/bruno.ogasawara/entrada/
DIR2=/home/bruno.ogasawara/backup/
DIR3=/home/bruno.ogasawara/producao/

cp -n $DIR1/*.war $DIR2
cp -n $DIR1/*.war $DIR3
cp -n $DIR2/*.war $DIR1
cp -n $DIR2/*.war $DIR3
cp -n $DIR3/*.war $DIR1
cp -n $DIR3/*.war $DIR2
```

> -n: will check if file already exists.it will not overwrite the existing file.